# how to config imagePullSecrets in kubernetes pod with initial container

Tags: kubernetes

I am pulling image from server in kubernetes(v1.15.2) pod, I am using this config to auth my access in containers:

```
 "imagePullSecrets": [
          {
            "name": "regcred"
          }
        ]
```

but it seems not work with the initial containers, when pulling initial container,the kubernetes pod throw this error:

```
Failed to pull image "registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/app_k8s/fat/alpine-bash:3.8": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai_fat/alpine-bash, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

so how to specify the auth info with the initial containers of kubernetes pod to make it works? this is my full config:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: deployment-apollo-portal-server
  namespace: sre
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/sre/deployments/deployment-apollo-portal-server
  uid: bc8e94bb-524d-487e-b9bb-90624cfcace3
  resourceVersion: '479747'
  generation: 4
  creationTimestamp: '2020-05-31T05:34:08Z'
  labels:
    app: deployment-apollo-portal-server
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '4'
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
      {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"deployment-apollo-portal-server"},"name":"deployment-apollo-portal-server","namespace":"sre"},"spec":{"replicas":3,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"app":"pod-apollo-portal-server"}},"strategy":{"rollingUpdate":{"maxSurge":1,"maxUnavailable":1},"type":"RollingUpdate"},"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"app":"pod-apollo-portal-server"}},"spec":{"affinity":{"podAntiAffinity":{"preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution":[{"podAffinityTerm":{"labelSelector":{"matchExpressions":[{"key":"app","operator":"In","values":["pod-apollo-portal-server"]}]},"topologyKey":"kubernetes.io/hostname"},"weight":100}]}},"containers":[{"env":[{"name":"APOLLO_PORTAL_SERVICE_NAME","value":"service-apollo-portal-server.sre"}],"image":"apollo-portal-server:v1.0.0","imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent","livenessProbe":{"initialDelaySeconds":120,"periodSeconds":15,"tcpSocket":{"port":8070}},"name":"container-apollo-portal-server","ports":[{"containerPort":8070,"protocol":"TCP"}],"readinessProbe":{"initialDelaySeconds":10,"periodSeconds":5,"tcpSocket":{"port":8070}},"securityContext":{"privileged":true},"volumeMounts":[{"mountPath":"/apollo-portal-server/config/application-github.properties","name":"volume-configmap-apollo-portal-server","subPath":"application-github.properties"},{"mountPath":"/apollo-portal-server/config/apollo-env.properties","name":"volume-configmap-apollo-portal-server","subPath":"apollo-env.properties"}]}],"dnsPolicy":"ClusterFirst","initContainers":[{"command":["bash","-c","curl
      --connect-timeout 2 --max-time 5 --retry 60 --retry-delay 1
      --retry-max-time 120
      service-apollo-admin-server-dev.sre:8090"],"image":"alpine-bash:3.8","name":"check-service-apollo-admin-server-dev"},{"command":["bash","-c","curl
      --connect-timeout 2 --max-time 5 --retry 60 --retry-delay 1
      --retry-max-time 120
      service-apollo-admin-server-test-alpha.sre:8090"],"image":"alpine-bash:3.8","name":"check-service-apollo-admin-server-alpha"},{"command":["bash","-c","curl
      --connect-timeout 2 --max-time 5 --retry 60 --retry-delay 1
      --retry-max-time 120
      service-apollo-admin-server-test-beta.sre:8090"],"image":"alpine-bash:3.8","name":"check-service-apollo-admin-server-beta"},{"command":["bash","-c","curl
      --connect-timeout 2 --max-time 5 --retry 60 --retry-delay 1
      --retry-max-time 120
      service-apollo-admin-server-prod.sre:8090"],"image":"alpine-bash:3.8","name":"check-service-apollo-admin-server-prod"}],"restartPolicy":"Always","volumes":[{"configMap":{"items":[{"key":"application-github.properties","path":"application-github.properties"},{"key":"apollo-env.properties","path":"apollo-env.properties"}],"name":"configmap-apollo-portal-server"},"name":"volume-configmap-apollo-portal-server"}]}}}}
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pod-apollo-portal-server
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: pod-apollo-portal-server
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: volume-configmap-apollo-portal-server
          configMap:
            name: configmap-apollo-portal-server
            items:
              - key: application-github.properties
                path: application-github.properties
              - key: apollo-env.properties
                path: apollo-env.properties
            defaultMode: 420
      initContainers:
        - name: check-service-apollo-admin-server-dev
          image: >-
            registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai_fat/alpine-bash:3.8
          command:
            - bash
            - '-c'
            - >-
              curl --connect-timeout 2 --max-time 5 --retry 60 --retry-delay 1
              --retry-max-time 120 service-apollo-admin-server-dev.sre:8090
          resources: {}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        - name: check-service-apollo-admin-server-alpha
          image: >-
            registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai_fat/alpine-bash:3.8
          command:
            - bash
            - '-c'
            - >-
              curl --connect-timeout 2 --max-time 5 --retry 60 --retry-delay 1
              --retry-max-time 120
              service-apollo-admin-server-test-alpha.sre:8090
          resources: {}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        - name: check-service-apollo-admin-server-beta
          image: >-
            registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai_fat/alpine-bash:3.8
          command:
            - bash
            - '-c'
            - >-
              curl --connect-timeout 2 --max-time 5 --retry 60 --retry-delay 1
              --retry-max-time 120
              service-apollo-admin-server-test-beta.sre:8090
          resources: {}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        - name: check-service-apollo-admin-server-prod
          image: >-
            registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai_fat/alpine-bash:3.8
          command:
            - bash
            - '-c'
            - >-
              curl --connect-timeout 2 --max-time 5 --retry 60 --retry-delay 1
              --retry-max-time 120 service-apollo-admin-server-prod.sre:8090
          resources: {}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      containers:
        - name: container-apollo-portal-server
          image: >-
            registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai_fat/apollo-portal-server:v1.0.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8070
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: APOLLO_PORTAL_SERVICE_NAME
              value: service-apollo-portal-server.sre
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: volume-configmap-apollo-portal-server
              mountPath: /apollo-portal-server/config/application-github.properties
              subPath: application-github.properties
            - name: volume-configmap-apollo-portal-server
              mountPath: /apollo-portal-server/config/apollo-env.properties
              subPath: apollo-env.properties
          livenessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 8070
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            periodSeconds: 15
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          readinessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 8070
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            periodSeconds: 5
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      securityContext: {}
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - weight: 100
              podAffinityTerm:
                labelSelector:
                  matchExpressions:
                    - key: app
                      operator: In
                      values:
                        - pod-apollo-portal-server
                topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
status:
  observedGeneration: 4
  replicas: 4
  updatedReplicas: 2
  unavailableReplicas: 4
  conditions:
    - type: Available
      status: 'False'
      lastUpdateTime: '2020-05-31T05:34:08Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2020-05-31T05:34:08Z'
      reason: MinimumReplicasUnavailable
      message: Deployment does not have minimum availability.
    - type: Progressing
      status: 'False'
      lastUpdateTime: '2020-05-31T06:08:24Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2020-05-31T06:08:24Z'
      reason: ProgressDeadlineExceeded
      message: >-
        ReplicaSet "deployment-apollo-portal-server-dc65dcf6b" has timed out
        progressing.
```

Comment: can you ensure `regcred` secret present in `sre` namespace? Also be sure with provided cred you can pull image in locally or without init container

Comment: yes, I am sure the regcred in the namespace and this regcred was using in the other cluster and works fine.@hoque

Comment: Config seems valid, I'd check twice if `regcred` exists in namespace and has type `kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson`.

Comment: yes,it works. I restart the deployment's pods@EgorStambakio

Comment: @Dolphin Could you please describe the actions you have taken in order to solve your issue in a form of an answer?